# C# Xamarin Android Multi Dex app with a custom application class that runs on pre-Lollipop

Tags: c#, android

I came across 65K limit and enabled Multidex, after that my was not instalkling on pre-Lollipop devices. As a result of hours of debugging and searching I found a solution [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64234/multi-dex-app-with-a-custom-application-class-that-runs-on-pre-lollipop).

I changed the subclass of  Application according to accepted answer, everything was working fine till now.

I recently found out that i had given some code handling in the class as a work around whenever the app runs into an unhandled exceptions. So when i am debugging , I see that it never enters the `Oncreate()` and my workaround has no effect on my App.

After some research i came across the `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication class` in Java that may solve my problem. But i can't find anything like this in my SDK manager now I am able to install it in any other way.

Does Xamarin even support this feature ?

Is there anyother way to solve this? or am i in the correct direction ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution you refer to is out of date. Now you do not need to create a custom MultiDexApplication class to make multidex work in Xamarin.
Also, `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` is not available in Xamarin. The following is steps to enable multidex in your project.

1. In Android Project Properties, check `Enable Multi-Dex`
   [image]
2. Create a custom `multidex.keep` file in your Android project and set the build action as `MultiDexMainDexList`
3. There is a bug from Xamarin on the auto generated multidex.keep file ([Link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59036)). So you will need to add in some .class file in your newly created `multidex.keep` file.

   ```
   mono/MonoPackageManager.class 
   mono/MonoRuntimeProvider.class
   mono/MonoPackageManager_Resources.class
   mono/android/app/NotifyTimeZoneChanges.class
   mono/android/app/ApplicationRegistration.class
   ```
4. Add in additional class that is needed in your application into the `multidex.keep` file.
5. You might need to perform the following:

   ```
   - Clean project
   - Close Visual Studio
   - Delete all bin and obj folder
   - Open back your solution
   - Clean and build again
   ```

Comment: Thanks,for the reply

Comment: I found multidex.keep file but it was empty. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Where you found the multidex.keep file? It is suppose to be created your own file.

Comment: Hi, 
I found it under obj/(Debug|Release)/multidex.keep, it was in the link you provided. I am new to xamarin.Android i don't really know what multidex.keep file is.

Comment: You should add the multidex.keep file into your Android project as describe in step 2. Then put in the list of items mention in step 3 into the multidex.keep file.

Comment: I tried your solution , it isn't working.
I am on Xamarin 4.2.2.11 and Xamarin.Android 7.0.2.42 version , if this makes any diffence.
if possible can you show a  multidex.keep file ,because i am confused whether to add new lines between the classes.

Comment: I am getting 09-22 11:03:45.700 E/AndroidRuntime(25961): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md581e96f9558deb1332c31e4ec59605f26.ExceptionHandlingApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myapp-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/myapp-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] on device logs .